# Slick slider сделать не активными кнопки или скрыть их

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Как скрыть или сделать неактивными кастомные кнопки слайдера, если мало слайдов для прокрутки?
Кнопки сделал так

```
jQuery('.slick-list').before('<div class="slick-arrows"><div class="slick-prev slick-arrow"></div><div class="slick-next slick-arrow"></div></div>');
jQuery('.slick-prev').click(function(){
    jQuery('.slick-slider').slick('slickPrev');
});
jQuery('.slick-next').click(function(){
    jQuery('.slick-slider').slick('slickNext');
});
```

Comment: А чем вас стандартные `arrows` не устраивали?

Comment: Тем, что они идут по бокам, а мне нужно было кнопки в один блок засунуть, и поместить их над слайдами

Comment: используйте опцию `appendArrows` или на худой конец - `padding-top` слайдеру и абсолютно спозиционированные стрелки.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас не хвататает слайдов slick сам скрывает елементы навигации.
И если вам нужны кастомные елементы для этого лучше использовать опции slick `prevArrow` и `nextArrow`

```js
$('.js-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  // slidesToScroll: 1,
  // arrows: false,
  prevArrow: $('.js-gallery-prev'),
  nextArrow: $('.js-gallery-next'),
  infinite: false,
  dots: false,
  autoplay: false,
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <!-- Навигация для слайдера -->
  <div class="slider-nav">
    <span class="slider-nav__arrow js-gallery-prev">PREV</span>
    <span class="slider-nav__arrow js-gallery-next">NEXT</span>
  </div>
 <!-- /---/ -->
  <div class="b-slider js-slider">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/500x250?text=1&fc=111111&bg=eaeaea">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/500x250?text=2&fc=111111&bg=eaeaea">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/500x250?text=3&fc=111111&bg=eaeaea">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/500x250?text=4&fc=111111&bg=eaeaea">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/500x250?text=5&fc=111111&bg=eaeaea">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись, но данные кнопки идут по бокам блока со слайдами, а мне нужно их вывести в один общий блок над блоком со слайдами, можно ли это сделать?

Comment: @Makissm, можно для этого используйте опции slick `prevArrow` и `nextArrow` при инициализации слайдера.
Пример обновил.

Comment: при таком варианте работает только последний слайдер, слайдеры выше не работают.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду что смещается только на 1 слайд, это потому что в опциях указано `infinite: false`. Тоесть отключить бесконечную прокрутку.
Рекомендую вам внимательней почитать о [настройках](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings) slick

Comment: Я писал про несколько слайдеров, а не про слайд.
Разобрался дополнил ваш вариант appendArrows и уникализировал его для каждого слайдера, теперь все корректно работает.